# Counting unique buckets from aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to get the unique count for all labels used on a set of  documents.  In order to do that, and have the json returned in the bucket (cardinality doesnt return json and count together), I need to write a pipeline query.

My query gets me half way there, but I'm missing the second part that counts the number of buckets a label is in.

Here's my query

```
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs" : {
     unique_count : {
        "composite" : [
           "metadataId" : {
             "terms" :{"field" : "document.metadata.id"}
           },
           "label" : {
             "terms" :{"field" : "document.label"}
           }
        ]
     }
  }
}
```

This produces

```
...
"buckets" : [
  {
    "key" : {
      "metadataId" : "1",
      "label" : "label one"
    },
    "doc_count" : 2
  },
  {
    "key" : {
      "metadataId" : "2",
      "label" : "label one"
    },
    "doc_count" : 1
  },
  {
    "key" : {
      "metadataId" : "3",
      "label" : "label three"
    },
    "doc_count" : 3
  }
]
...
```

The problem I'm facing is that each bucket is considered unique and the sum of the unique counts is what I would like to return.  For example, in the buckets above the label "label one" is contained within two buckets, so it's doc_count should be 2, while "label three" should have a doc_count of 1.

After the last phase in the pipeline I'd like to see the following output:

```
"buckets" : [
  {
    "label" : "label one"
    "doc_count" : 2
  },
  {
    "label" : "label three"
    "doc_count" : 1
  }
]
```

I've tried all sorts of things, but they're just not getting me close to the output I need.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try using "terms" aggregation on your label field which will return label as "key" and number of matching documents in "doc_count" fields of the output.

Comment: We started out using that, but the count is determined by a combo key (metadataId and label) which a terms agg cannot handle (at least as far as I understand)

Comment: Then you need nested terms aggs by figuring out which field must be picked first: metadataId or labels.

Comment: It doesnt matter which one is picked first.  The data is partitioned by both

Comment: Then best would be to terms aggs on labels nested with terms aggs on metadataId.

Comment: Do you mind showing an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the nested terms aggregations where first level aggs would be on label and the second level on metadataId field. The aggs block should look something like:

```
"aggs" : {
  "labels": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "label.keyword",
      "size": 1000
    },
    "aggs": {
      "metadata": {
        "terms": {
          "field": metadataId.keyword",
          "size": 1000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As output, you will get buckets of labels with `key` as label value and `doc_count` with count of docs matching that label. Each label bucket will have a nested buckets of metadataId with `key` as metadataId value and `doc_count` with count of docs matching that label and metadataId.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this, but it did not work as the first `aggs` bucketed all the labels, but the second `aggs` bucketed ALL the metadataId's from all the documents, NOT just the documents returned from the parent `aggs`.   Is there a way to have one agg feed into the next?

Comment: The basic idea behind nested aggs is to feed the output of first aggs to second. May be can you provide the aggs that you tried ?

Comment: Yes!  I did end up solving the issue by using a nested aggregation.  I'll have to update with the answer.   Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Awesome news, if this resolves your problem, please mark it as solution :)

Comment: This isn't the solution.  A nested aggs is... this example is not nested.  Please feel free to update this though and I can mark it as the answer

Comment: By nested aggregation, I meant aggregation within another aggregation.. similar to a nested for loop, one in another :). It wasn't about "nested" type aggregation.

Comment: ah, well a "nested type" aggregation was the fix  :)

Thanks for your help and time!